# C RSA_public_encrypt mysterious seg fault

Tags: c

Getting segmentation fault on RSA_public_encrypt and I can't find the actual cause/solution.

I have tried almost everything I can think of including every single variable/definition combination.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Heres the code:

```c
void inputRead(int sockfd) {
  //if (fork() == 0) {
    char pubKey[MAXBUF];
    read(sockfd, pubKey, MAXBUF);// Reading the public key sent from the server
    RSA *rsa2 = NULL;
    BIO *key_bio2 = BIO_new_mem_buf(pubKey, -1);
    PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(key_bio2, &rsa2, 0, NULL);
    while (1){
        char encrypted[MAXBUF]={0};
        char buffer[MAXBUF];

        scanf("%s", buffer);
        if (!RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(buffer), (unsigned char *) buffer, (unsigned char *) encrypted, rsa2, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) {
          log_ssl_err("EncryptInit for cipher failed");
        }
        char* data = b_encode(encrypted, strlen((char*) encrypted));
        write(sockfd, data, strlen(data));
        free(data);
    }
    exit(1);
  //}
}
```

Here is the full error reported by Valgrind:

```
==69377== Invalid read of size 8
==69377==    at 0x4A00A84: RSA_public_encrypt (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==69377==    by 0x1099C4: inputRead (login.c:102)
==69377==    by 0x109C81: Client (login.c:144)
==69377==    by 0x10964D: main (login.c:39)
==69377==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: How large is the data being encrypted, and is it definitely a terminated string of length smaller than the modulus size of the key being used, less 42?

Comment: @WhozCraig I've tried with several lengths 1-10 I've even tried using it with hardcoded strings instead, always "Invalid read of size 8".

Comment: Some actual error checking and size validations are warranted in this code regardless. Any number of things may not be living up to your assumptions. You're ignoring the results of `read`, the results of scanf, and the results of pem-load. Its not paranoia if they're really out to get you, and thumbing ones nose at [Spencer's Sixth Commandment](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) is never a good idea.

Comment: Every time I see strlen() in any context where there may be no guarantee of a valid NUL-terminated char array, (ie, one with a nul ONLY at the end), I get the jitters:(

Comment: @bakedBEANZZZZZZZZZZZ - Is _`the public key sent from the server`_ _nul terminated_?